# Storing a received cookie in a file with curl

Tags: curl, cookies

I have a problem with curl and it is driving me crazy. I'm trying to authenticate to an API with curl and get a cookie back. I need to store this cookie into a file because I need it for the actual API queries later on. I also need to send a client cert and key to the API. My problem is
that the response contains the cookie I need, but curl refuses to write the cookie into the specified file. I can see the cookie in the response header "Set-Cookie'

So far, my curl call looks like this:

```
curl --cert mycertfile.cert --key mykeyfile.key -v -k -c cookie.txt --output response.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d <some json payload> <API URL>
```

The response is correctly written into the specified file. The cookie file is created by curl and contains 3 lines of comments saying it was created by libcurl ect., but no cookie.

What am I missing here ?

curl version 7.72.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), Kernel is 5.7.0-kali1-amd64

Comment: no saved cookies means curl didn't have any to store...

Comment: The cookie is present in the response, and according to the curl documentation -c <filename> should write cookies in the response into the specified file, which in my case does not happen for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the API has some strange behaviour and returns some kind of weird cookie even with a HTTP 401 Unauthorized response, and curl seems to ignore the cookie header in that case.